# Applying cuFFT to OpenGL Vertex Buffer Objects

Tags: opengl, cuda, glsl, cufft

So the `cufftComplex` type is an array with `n` structs with an `x` and a `y`-field, respectively representing the real and the imaginary parts of each complex number.

On the other hand, if I want to create a vertex buffer object in OpenGL with an `x-` and `y-` field, i.e. a 2D vertex or just a vertex buffer object that also represents `n` complex numbers, I would have to create a `2n` sized array of floats with a layout like this:

```
x0 y0 | x1 y1 | ... | xn yn
```

I then write it to the VBO by calling:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, n * sizeof(GLfloat), complex_values_array, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

I would like to Fourier-transform an image with cuFFT, and display e.g. the magnitude of the complex values. How do I resolve this incompatibility between the two data types? Is there a way for cuFFT to act on VBO's?

**Edit:**

Perhaps I should write a CUDA-kernel that takes the cufftComplex type and maps the magnitude of each complex number to a 1D-VBO. Or a CUDA-kernel that maps the cufftComplex type to a 2D-VBO. I do not know what the overhead would be, since it's device-> device I expect it to be manageable.

Comment: cufft can stride and scatter both its input and its output, just like FFTW can.  But if you want to display the *magnitude* of the complex values, that is a separate issue.  It needs to be calculated.  It's not merely an "incompatibility between the two data types".

Comment: Yes but I thought I could feed complex values to the vertex shader and calculate the magnitude there.

Comment: Probably you could.  That's the first mention of your intention to write a shader that I've seen in the question, although I acknowledge its tagged `glsl`.  Anyway its not an incompatibility between datatypes.  It's a calculation that has to be performed; cufft won't do that for you.  You could do it in a CUDA kernel (and also do any necessary data shuffling there as well) or perhaps in a shader.  Anyway, using CUDA-OpenGL Interop, you could map an OpenGL resource to CUDA.  CUFFT (or your magnitude/shuffle kernel) could populate that resource, and then you could turn it back over to OpenGL.

Comment: That's ultimately what I did, a CUDA kernel that takes cufftComplex and writes it to an openGL resource. The performance impact wasn't too bad.

Comment: @PatronBernard: Could you add your solution as an answer please, so that this question falls off the unanswered queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by writing a kernel as follows:

```
__global__ void cufftComplex2Float(float* vbo_magnitude, Complex *z, const int width, const int height){
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int j = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    float magnitude = pow(z[j*height + i].x, (float)2) + pow(z[j*height + i].y, (float)2);
    vbo_magnitude[j*height + i] = (PI2 + atanf(sqrt(0.1*magnitude))) / PI;
};
```

It involves no host-device transfers so it's pretty quick.